# Issue overloading the operator c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I keep getting the following errors

Error (active)  E0349   no operator "<<" matches these operands
Error   C2678   binary '<<': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::ostream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

I know the issue is that there's something going wrong or missing when I try to overload the operator and I think its something small at this point, but I have no idea anymore. Any help would be appreciated.

.h file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ostream>

using namespace std;

#ifndef ACCOUNT_H
#define ACCOUNT_H

class account {

private:
    int acct_ID;
    string acct_name;
    float acct_balance;
    static int next_id;

public:
    account();
    account(account& rhs);
    ~account();
    account(int acct_ID, string acct_name, float acct_balance);
    void set_ID(int acct_ID);
    int get_ID()const;
    void set_name(string acct_name);
    void input();
    void set_balance(float acct_balance);
    ostream& display(ostream& stream);
    

};
ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, account& Account); //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

#endif
```

.cpp file

```
#include "Account.h"

account::account(): acct_ID{0},acct_name{0},acct_balance{ 0 }{}

account::account(account& rhs): acct_ID{ rhs.acct_ID }, acct_name{ rhs.acct_name }, acct_balance{ rhs.acct_balance }{}

account::account(int ID, string name, float balance) :acct_ID{ ID }, acct_name{ name }, acct_balance{ balance } {


}

int account::next_id = 0;

account::~account() {}
void account::set_ID(int ID) {
    acct_ID = ID;
}

int account::get_ID()const {
    int acct_ID = 0;
    return acct_ID;
}

void account::set_name(string name) {
    acct_name = name;
}
void account::input() {
    
    cout << "Enter the name: ";
    cin >> acct_name;
    float x;
    cout << "Enter the balance: ";
    cin >> x;
    acct_balance += x;
    acct_ID = next_id;
    next_id++;
    
}
//!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
ostream& account::display(ostream& stream) {
    stream << "Account name: " << this->acct_name;
    stream << "Account balance: " << this->acct_balance;
    stream << "Account ID: " << this->acct_ID;
    return stream;
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream,account& Account) {
    stream << Account.display(stream);
    return stream;
} //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


void account::set_balance(float balance)
{
    acct_balance = balance;
}
```

Comment: `stream << Account.display(stream);` doesn't look right, since the return value of `Account.display(stream)` is, itself, an `ostream&` and there isn't an overload for `ostream << ostream`. It looks like you just want `Account.display(stream); return stream;`. Or possibly even just `return Account.display(stream);`

Comment: Better to avoid `using namespace std` - see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've used:

```
stream << Account.display(stream);
```

inside the overloaded `operator<<`. This is a problem because `account::display` returns a `std::ostream` and there is no overload of `operator<<` that takes a `std::ostream` as a parameter.

##### Method 1

To **solve** this you can add a **friend declaration** for the overloaded `operator<<` inside the class and change the implementation of `operator<<` to as shown below:

```
class account
{
    //other members as before
   
   //friend declaration for overloaded operator<<
   friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, account& Account);
};

//implementation of operator<<
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream,account& Account) {
    stream << Account.acct_ID<<" "<< Account.acct_name<<" "<<Account.acct_balance<<" "<<Account.acct_ID;
    return stream;
}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/-lW8F9nWi)

##### Method 2

Another way to solve this is to replace `stream << Account.display(stream);` with `return  Account.display(stream);` as shown below:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream,account& Account) {
    return  Account.display(stream); //changed this
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/LlxFZbV3M)

Comment: You don't need a `friend` declaration since `display` is a public member of `account`. Seems simpler to just correct the usage of `display` in the `operator<<` overload. And also makes it a little easier to adapt this to a situation where, say, `account` is actually supposed to be a polymorphic base class and `display` can be made `virtual` but `operator<<` the free function cannot.

Comment: @NathanPierson Note that in my modified example, i have not used `display`.  Also, since there is a overloaded `operator<<` for `account`, `display` is no longer needed for the given example.